In DebugView (GA4), the same device is displayed several times under "Fix device error"?
As you can already see from the question, it's about the DebugView of Google Analytics 4. When testing (in preview mode of the Tag Manager), the same device is always displayed umpteen times in the DebugView (not always the same number). My DebugView
The parameter "debug_mode" was initially set to "true" because it is a test store. Now I have removed the parameter. This means that only one device should be displayed in the DebugView, as I am the only one in preview mode (GTM), or not? Because despite removing the parameter "debug_view" I still see so many devices.
We have 3 other similar stores that are online and only one device "web 10" is displayed when I test through the preview mode.
What could be the problem? I don't have an adblocker, extension, multiple tabs etc. open.
Is it because the extended e-commerce events such as "add_to_cart", "view_item", "begin_checkout", "purchase" etc. are not being sent correctly in GA4 under "e-commerce purchases" reports due to the multiple devices? See picture and the markings.E-Commerce-Purchases GA4
Because I always see that a "view_item" has been sent in one of the "web 10" devices and a "purchase" event has been sent in the other "web 10" device, instead of everything being sent via one device.
As a result, the purchase process in GA4 is not filled correctly, am I right?
So please suggest a solution.
P.s. The e-commerce events have been stored in the code by our programmer, in preview mode all events are also fired correctly with the important parameters. Or could I have overlooked something there?
Thanks in advance! :D
i removed the parameter "debug_mode", i paused the e-commerce events in google tag manager, didn't solve the problem either. I have set the filter status to "test" in GA4 under data filter. This was previously deactivated.
I also removed the internal traffic where I had stored an IP address.
